# Fast alternative to java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(..)/encode(..)

Tags: java, character-encoding, encode, decode, performance

Anybody knows a faster way to do what `java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(..)`/`encode(..)` does?

It's currently one of the bottleneck of a technology that I'm using.

[EDIT]
Specifically, in my application, I changed one segment from a java-solution to a JNI-solution (because there was a C++ technology that was most suitable for my needs than the Java technology that I was using).

This change brought about some significant decrease in speed (and significant increase in cpu & mem usage).

Looking deeper into the JNI-solution that I used, the java application is communicating with the C++ application via byte[]. These byte[] are produced by Charset.encode(..) from the java side and passed to the C++ side. Then when the C++ response with a byte[], it gets decoded in the java side via Charset.decode(..).

Running this against a profiler, I see that Charset.decode(..) and Charset.encode(..) both took a significantly long time compared to the whole execution time of the JNI-solution (I profiled only the JNI-solution because it's something I could whip up quite quickly. I'll profile the whole application on a latter date once I free up my schedule :-) ).

Upon reading further regarding my problem, it's seems that it's a known problem with Charset.encode(..) and decode(..) and it's being addressed in Java7. However, moving to Java7 is not an option for me (for now) due to some constraints.

Which is why I ask here if somebody knows a Java5 solution / alternative to this (Sorry, should have mentioned that this was for Java5 sooner) ? :-)

Comment: What's the functional requirement? (the bigger picture)

Comment: Any particular charset? UTF-8 decode should be faster in recent releases. I would expect I/O to be the actual bottleneck.

Comment: What is the source of the bytes for `decode()` and the destination for the characters? What is the source of characters for `encode()` and the destination for the bytes? Your performance problems may relate more to allocating and copying input and output than the actual encoding or decoding process.

Comment: Good day, I've just added edit my question by adding more information. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The javadoc for `encode()` and `decode()` make it clear that these are convenience methods. For example, for [encode()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29):

> Convenience method that encodes
>   Unicode characters into bytes in this
>   charset.
>
> An invocation of this method upon a
>   charset cs returns the same result as
>   the expression

```
 cs.newEncoder()
   .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
   .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
   .encode(bb);
```

> except that it is potentially more
>   efficient because it can cache
>   encoders between successive
>   invocations.

The language is a bit vague there, but you might get a performance boost by not using these convenience methods. Create and configure the encoder once, and then re-use it:

```
 CharsetEncoder encoder = cs.newEncoder()
   .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
   .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);

 encoder.encode(...);
 encoder.encode(...);
 encoder.encode(...);
 encoder.encode(...);
```

It always pays to read the javadoc, even if you think you already know the answer.

Comment: In Java 1.6 (at least) the implementation of `CharSet.encode(...)` uses an encoder that is cached using thread locals, and repeats the setup calls (`onMalformed ...` etc) each time.  By doing your own caching, you would only save the overhead of a thread local fetch, and the setup calls.  This is probably insignificant ... though the profiler should tell you that.

Comment: Actually, I've read the javadoc & the source code for Charset as well. And 1.5 has that thread local buffering as well. And I don't see anything there (code-wise and profiler-wise) that could produce the slow down. My guess is that the culprit is the `for(;;)`.

Answer (score 2):

First part - it is bad idea in general to pass arrays into JNI code. Because of GC, Java has to *copy* arrays. In the worth case array will be copied two times - on the way to JNI code and on the way back :)

Because of that `Buffer` class hierarchy was introduced. And of course Java dev team creates a nice way to encode/decode chars:

`Charser#newDecoder` returns you `CharsetDecoder`, which could be used to comvert `ByteBuffer` to `CharBuffer` according to a `Charset`. There are two main method versions:

```
CoderResult decode(ByteBuffer in, CharBuffer out, boolean endOfInput)
CharBuffer decode(ByteBuffer in)
```

For the max performance you need the first one. It has no hidden memory allocations inside.

You need to note that Encoder/Decoder could maintance internal state, so be careful (for example if you map from 2byte encoding and input buffer has one half of char...). Also encoder/decoder are not threadsafe

Answer (score 1):

There are very few reasons to "squeeze" a string in a byte array.
I would recommend to write the C functions to take utf-16 strings as parameters.
This way there is no need for any conversion.